Cannot change to edit mode... hidden objects?
I have a model that was provided to me,  where I cannot change to edit mode. I created that cube and dropped in the iHAB object group as the screenshot shows, and now the cube disappeared so I cannot longer individually select it.
It is like there is something that hides whatever is inside the iHAB group. I tried pressing every button I can see, or menu options found, but no success here.
thanks for any pointers or help


From your image, looks like that's just an instance (orange group icon) and real object is hidden (white icon, same name as orange) you can only edit the real object and you need to un hide it by pressing the eye icon on the right

The "white icon" is just as much an instance.

Problem is it won't let me click the eye on the white icon object only on the parent.

@JoseLagares Sorry, my bad, there should be an icon on the right for the white one, probably looks like a rectangle

Hi!  There is no eye icon... only a camera icon to the right of the white child object.

It looks like you either have an instanced collection or a linked collection containing that model (from either the Asset Manager or using the menu File > Link, and it could also have been packed into the file).
The issue is that Linked data isn't meant to be edited on the spot. Their purpose is to be "linked" from an external .blend into a building scene for save usage, or to be multiplied in a scene without loading them more than once in memory.
If it's an instanced collection, you should be able to find the original non-instantiated collection somewhere (the outliner set in Blend-File should be able to show it and tell where it is).
If it's a linked library, firstly we need to make sure it isn't packed in the .blend file anymore. You can unpack it via the menu File > External Data > Unpack Linked Libraries0
Then you have three options from there:
A. Open the original file containing the model and work there.
It's what you should do if you want to make definitive changes to the model rather than changes specific to another project or file.
It is very easy if you imported that asset from the Asset Manager :  RMB the asset in the manager > Open Blend File:

Otherwise, just open the blend file as any other blend file.
B: Delete that linked asset, and Append the model instead
This is what you should do if you want to make changes specific to a project or file.

Either change the Asset Manager's default action to Append, and drag the asset in the viewport again:

Or Use the menu File > Append, and navigate to the asset's containing collection again.

C: Add library override.
This is typically for animation. Linked characters can't be changed, but a library override allows to pose and animate the armature in pose mode.

RMB the top collection of the asset in the outliner > Library Override > Make > Selected & Content


That's it, you should be able to make slight changes to assets.
But from there, you could also make the data local, which basically an append with extra steps, but just to show it can be done:

Disable the outliner's object content display:

⇧ Shift click the unfold icon of your asset's containing collection to unfold the whole hierarchy.
Hold down ⇧ Shift and click the first and last element of the asset hierarchy to select them
 RMB > ID Data > Make Local


Their link-with-arrow icon, indicative of linked asset with library overrides, should be gone. And the objects are now locally in your scene.

Hi and thanks for all the info, however there is no separate blender file this is the only file. Everything is suppose to be on this file but it is not visible.  I created a cube, then dropped it into the group, and it just disappear from the hierarchy.

Do you mean you downloaded a file and it opens with the model like this? Then it's either an instanced collection, and you should be able to find the original non-instanciated collection somewhere (the outliner set in Blend-File should be able to show it and tell whete it is), or it's a linked library buth which was then packed into the blend file. You can unpack it via the menu File > External Data > Unpack Linked Libraries, then the procedures in my answer should work. If you encounter any issue, please share your file ;)

Hey! this worked!! ... by doing the Unpack Linked Libraries all parts were separated into their own files.... thank you so much!
